# What am I missing in this React to-do app that I'm making?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Yes, I'm new to React, and I'm trying to make the (infamous?) to-do app from scratch. So far I just have a todo component and then the main app. Here's my code - first is the Todo component:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Todo extends Component {

    static defaultProps = {
        completed: false,
    }

    static propTypes = {
        completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        // name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            completed: false,
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {!this.state.completed && <div>
                    <span>{this.props.name}</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => {this.markCompleted()}}/>
                </div>}
            </div>
        )
    }

    markCompleted = () => {
        this.setState((currentState) => {
            return {
                completed: !currentState.completed
            }
        })
    }
}

export default Todo;
```

And then the main App component...

```
import React from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
      this.state = {
        todos: [{id: 1, name: 'take out trash'}, {id: 2, name: 'feed the cat'}]
      }
  }

  render(){
    let textInput;
    const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} name={todo.name} completed={todo.completed}/>)
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <input type="text" ref={(el) => {textInput = el}} />
         <button onClick={() => {this.addTodo(textInput.value)}}>Click to Add a Todo</button>
        {todos}
      </div>
    );
  }

  addTodo = (todoName) => {
    const newTodo = {id: this.state.todos.length + 1, name: todoName};
    const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} name={todo.name} completed={todo.completed}/>)
    todos.push(newTodo)
    console.log(this.state.todos);
      this.setState({
        todos
      })
      // console.log(todos)
    }
}

export default App;
```

So I'm left with a conundrum. On the initial render, the state of the todos array maps out just fine. However, when I type in a todo and click the button to add the todo, all of the names of the other todos vanish, and only the name of the last pushed todo appears. So if I were to add a todo "pay bills," then the checkboxes for "take out the trash" and "feed the cat" will still be visible, but the names of those todos will no longer be visible. I can click the checkboxes just fine to remove the todos as well, but I wish my todos array would cooperate. I think I'm also supposed to use `.filter` to properly filter out todos whose completed state is marked as `true`. Are the other names disappearing because of the `todoName` parameter I've added in the `addTodo` method? Is that causing all previous todo names to be undefined? I am really trying to learn, and I'm open to all help and suggestions to improve. I would request that we work with the code that I have already, as I've seen how other people have made the todo app before, and I don't want to just copy and observe someone else's code, because I feel that that detracts from my learning. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I did some corrections on the `App` class:

In `addTodo`, simplify it, you can push the state array like this:

```js
  addTodo = (todoName) => {
    const newTodo = {id: this.state.todos.length + 1, name: todoName};
      this.setState({
        todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo]
      })
      console.log(this.state.todos);
    }
```

Same for the render, you do not need that auxiliar todos you were using, just map the state like you were doing.

```js
  render(){
    let textInput;
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <input type="text" ref={(el) => {textInput = el}} />
         <button onClick={() => {this.addTodo(textInput.value)}}>Click to Add a Todo</button>
        {this.state.todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} name={todo.name} completed={todo.completed}/>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks - this works perfectly! May I ask though, how come we can just set state of `todos` as the array with the spread operator for the current state of `todos` and then the `newTodo`? I know I'm new, so I thought that pushing the `newTodo` into the `this.state.todos` would accomplish the same task. May I ask why your solution works the way that it does while mine bugs out? This question may or may not be too vague.

Comment: Please, review the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

There are two wrong things there, the map is not properly done, if you want to copy an array you may use slice() or [...arrayToCopy] 
const todos = this.state.todos.slice();
const todos = [...this.state.todos]

You can use map, but it won't be efficient. 

Later on, you are setting state without making any assignation to todos state, so that way it does not get updated. 

Please, open a new question if you have more doubts.